# Resync target servers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am working in a SQL Server environment with one master server and many target servers. It sometimes happens that for a reason or another one a target server may go out of sync.

I have the choice when that occurs to manually run the following stored procedure to re-sync the target server:

```
exec sp_resync_targetserver @server_name = 'RMAPP11DV1\PROJECT'
```

My assignment is to automate the process so that we do not have to manually run it. I should write a script and schedule it as a job that should run a a schedule time to selectively find and re-sync only the target servers that are currently out of sync.

This is my approach so far. It is not working as expected (can not do the re-sync when ran), that is why I need any one output. Thanks in advance:

```
use msdb
set nocount on;

if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.all_objects where name like '%#targetstatus%')  --deleting the table if it already exists
    drop table #targetstatus

create table #targetstatus
(
    server_id int not null,
    server_name nvarchar(300) not null,
    location nvarchar(350) null,
    time_zone_adjustment int not null,
    enlist_date datetime not null,
    last_poll_date datetime not null,
    status int not null,
    unread_instructions int not null,
    local_time datetime not null,
    enlisted_by_nt_user nvarchar(100) not null,
    poll_interval int not null
) 

insert into #targetstatus
    exec sp_help_targetserver

select * from #targetstatus 

if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.all_objects where name like '%#needresync%')  --deleting the table if it already exists
    drop table #needresync

create table #needresync -- will hold the target servers needing to be re-synced
(
    server_id int not null,
    server_name nvarchar(300) not null,
    location nvarchar(350) null,
    time_zone_adjustment int not null,
    enlist_date datetime not null,
    last_poll_date datetime not null,
    status int not null,
    unread_instructions int not null,
    local_time datetime not null,
    enlisted_by_nt_user nvarchar(100) not null,
    poll_interval int not null
) 

insert into #needresync
    select * 
    from #targetstatus 
    where status <> 1 -- we only want to run the syncing proc on the target with a status diff of #1

select * from #needresync 

declare @target_server varchar(100);
set @target_server = ' '

while @target_server <> ' '
begin
    set @target_server = (select max(server_name) from #needresync);
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_resync_targetserver @server_name = '@target_server';
    -- @target_server = @target_server + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not deleting the row out of `#needresync`. You must delete each row one by one inside the `while` loop.

However, a much easier method exists. You can use the [systargetservers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-systargetservers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) DMV without using any temp tables at all:

```
DECLARE @server sysname = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 FROM dbo.systargetservers WHERE status = 2);  --  2 = Re-sync Pending

WHILE (@server IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_resync_targetserver @server;
    SET @server = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 FROM dbo.systargetservers WHERE status = 2);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input Charlie. I will implement your solution and let you know how it went. Thanks again for taking your precious time to respond.